# What does an interpreter command do in unix/tcl?

Tags: unix, tcl

I am observing one command in my `TCL` code (interpreter) . the command name is `"interpreter"` .

I searched on the google for this command , but I did not get much information .

Can anyone explain about this command ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Do you mean `interp`? : http://www.astro.princeton.edu/~rhl/Tcl-Tk_docs/tcl/interp.n.html

Comment: no it is "interpreter" .

Comment: I don't know whether it is unix command or tcl command .. The execution of the script is pausing there .

Comment: Tcl doesn't have a built-in `interpreter` command.  Either your program, or some library it uses, defines that command.  You will need to add more details to your question if you want more help.

Comment: Nothing on the Tcler's Wiki claims that `interpreter` is a command for a particular Tcl package either. Whatever it is, it's not “well known”…

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I'm a year late, but maybe you're using [Expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect), a tcl plugin?

If you follow the link above search for `interpreter "` with `ctrl+f` you will find the following (bizarrely formatted) description:

> causes the user to be interactively prompted for Expect and Tcl commands. The result of each command is printed.
>
> Actions such as break and continue cause control structures (i.e., for, proc) to behave in the usual way. However return causes interpreter to return to its caller, while inter_return causes interpreter to cause a return in its caller. For example, if "proc foo" called interpreter which then executed the action inter_return, proc foo would return. Any other command causes interpreter to continue prompting for new commands.
>
> By default, the prompt contains two integers.
> The first integer describes the depth of the evaluation stack (i.e., how many times Tcl_Eval has been called). The second integer is the Tcl history identifier. The prompt can be set by defining a procedure called "prompt1" whose return value becomes the next prompt. If a statement has open quotes, parens, braces, or brackets, a secondary prompt (by default "+> ") is issued upon newline. The secondary prompt may be set by defining a procedure called "prompt2".

tl;dr: It pauses your script and allows you to execute tcl commands